# Incompatible Titanium modules when upgrading to 6.0.1.GA

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

My Android app is currently at SDK 5.3.1.GA, and I'd like to increase to 6.0.1.GA. When I update tiapp.xml, however, I get a build error for every module I am including. The full error is as follows:

```
[INFO]  Auto selecting device that closest matches 6.0
[INFO]  Auto selected device Pixel 7.1.1
[WARN]  Could not find a valid Titanium module id=com.tripvi.drawerlayout version=1.4.0 platform=android deploy-type=test
[WARN]  Could not find a valid Titanium module id=dk.napp.downloadmanager version=1.1.7 platform=android deploy-type=test
[WARN]  Could not find a valid Titanium module id=com.mykingdom.mupdf version=1.8 platform=android deploy-type=test
[WARN]  Could not find a valid Titanium module id=bencoding.blur version=0.3.0 platform=android deploy-type=test
[ERROR] Found incompatible Titanium Modules:
[ERROR]    id: com.tripvi.drawerlayout   version: 1.4.0  platform: android   min sdk: 5.1.0.GA
[ERROR]    id: dk.napp.downloadmanager   version: 1.1.7  platform: android   min sdk: 3.5.1.GA
[ERROR]    id: com.mykingdom.mupdf   version: 1.8    platform: android   min sdk: 3.1.3.GA
[ERROR]    id: bencoding.blur    version: 0.3.0  platform: android   min sdk: 5.0.2.GA
```

This is very confusing, because it seems to be telling me my SDK version is too low, when it is actually far higher than any of the "min sdk" messages. This builds just fine on 5.3.1.GA; the only thing I'm changing is 6.0.1.GA (which is installed). What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a newer version of the modules. Modules have to be recompiled for Titanium SDK 6+ (it was officially announced before). Have a look here:
http://skypanther.com/2016/10/rebuilding-modules-for-titanium-6/
on how to do this or have a look at the repos of the modules. Most of the already offer a Ti 6+ version.

- Drawerlayout: https://github.com/manumaticx/Ti.DrawerLayout/tree/master/android/dist
- MuPDF: https://github.com/manojdcoder/titanium-mupdf/tree/master/dist
- BlurView: https://github.com/konstantinbueschel/Ti.BlurView/tree/master/android/dist
- Download Manager: https://github.com/viezel/NappDownloadManager/tree/master/android/dist

Answer (score 0):

It was because I needed to include versions of the modules built for 6.0.0, as that SDK included some breaking changes.

Comment: Posted this just as it was answered below.